# Microsoft.Framework.Configuration and Lists

Tags: c#, xml, configurationmanager

I am using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration to build objects from xml. But it seems that I cannot build lists. Take for example the configuration file

```
<config>
  <vehicle>
    <description>Truck</description>
    <mpg>20</mpg>
    <paint>
      <majorcolor>white</majorcolor>
      <minorcolor>black</minorcolor>
    </paint>
  </vehicle>

  <vehicle>
    <description>Car</description>
    <mpg>30</mpg>
    <paint>
      <majorcolor>maroon</majorcolor>
      <minorcolor>white</minorcolor>
    </paint>
  </vehicle>
</config>
```

It has 2 vehicles. I want to store that in a list, but I cannot directly do that. When ran to following code:

```
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    config.AddXmlFile(path);
    var configuration = config.Build().GetSection("vehicle");

    var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
    configuration.Bind(vehicles);
```

It threw a FormatException "A duplicate key 'vehicle:description' was found. Line 12, position 18." Is there a way to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the problem with the exception. I rewrote the xml and fixed the code a little bit:

```
<config>
  <vehicles>
    <vehicle name="firstVehicle">
      ...
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle name="secondVehicle">
      ...
    </vehicle>
  </vehicles>
</config>
```

and added

```
internal class Vehicles
{
    // code
    public List<Vehicle> VehicleList;
    // more code
}
...
var configuration = config.Build().GetSection("vehicles");
var vehicles = new Vehicles();
configuration.Bind(vehicles);
```

But now I get empty VehicleList. Not sure why.

Comment: Try enclosing the `Vehicle` nodes in a `Vehicles` node.

Comment: Do you mean <vehicles> <vehicle>...</vehicle><vehicle>....</vehicle></vehicles> ? Why should that change anything?

Comment: It will deserialize the XML to a class with a `Vehicles` property of type `List<Vehicle>` (or possibly `Vehicle[]`).  With custom classes you can control such behavior with attributes; I don't know if you can with `ConfigurationBuilder`.

Comment: It still doesn't parse the file: A duplicate key vehicles:vehicle:description was found. I am not sure if I can use classes other than ConfigurationBuilder to build those objects out of the xml file.